# Why is this pandas df.loc() call selecting all the records that satisfy only one condition and not both?

Tags: pandas

So I have this dataframe

```
# list of strings 
lst = ['Geeks', 'For', 'Geeks', 'is', 'portal', 'for', 'Geeks'] 

# list of int 
lst2 = ["gdadsf", '23', 'gggg', '22', 'df', '66', '77'] 

# Calling DataFrame constructor after zipping 
# both lists, with columns specified 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), 
            columns =['Name', 'val']) 
df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')&('gggg' in df['val'].to_string())]
```

and the result is below, it selects all the rows that contain Geeks instead of just row 2

```
0   Geeks   gdadsf
2   Geeks   gggg
6   Geeks   77
```

Update:This is a continuation or a question that stemmed from [How do I test if a string is in a cell of a pandas data frame, cell that contains a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611513/how-do-i-test-if-a-string-is-in-a-cell-of-a-pandas-data-frame-cell-that-contain/60611657#60611657)

Update2: I if bring this close to the other questions referred above I get nothing in response to my query Notice the list of strings that are now stored in the cells

```
# list of strings 
lst = ['Geeks', 'For', 'Geeks', 'is', 'portal', 'for', 'Geeks'] 
# list of int 
lst2 = [["gdadsf",'jjjj'], ['23'], ['gggg','hhh'], ['22'], ['df'], ['66'], ['77','zzz'] ]
# Calling DataFrame constructor after zipping 
# both lists, with columns specified 
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, lst2)), 
            columns =['Name', 'val']) 
df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')&(df['val'].str.contains('gggg'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_string()` concatenate everything to a single long string. Essentially your code is

```
df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')& True]
```

which gives you all the rows having `Name` equals `'Geeks'`. So you don't want that, you want:

```
df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')&( df['val'].str.contains('gggg'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be true every time because the membership function `in` would evaluate to `True` every time.

you should add similar condition, checking for equalto value. like below.

```
print(df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')&(df['val']=='gggg')])
```

if you have multiple values to check in the `and` condition use `isin` like below.

```
print(df.loc[(df['Name']=='Geeks')&(df.val.isin(['gggg','77']))])
```

Comment: It is the opposite, in the real life scenario (see the linked question in the update)  I have a list of strings there . My understand of the order of opperations in ('gggg' in df['val'].to_string())] is that df['val'] will be turned into string (each cell on each row and then the interpreter will check to see if the string in in each cell

Comment: yes, it is opposite but it doesn't make any difference for your case, as you need to specify the specific value to be checked either checking value in the df values or checking df values in your specified values. anyways you need to write your specific value. i don't know how much feasible solution it would be from time complexity point of view.

Comment: see the other question ...those list of strings are quite long and complex I can test if ['aaa','bbb','ccc'] is in ['aaa'] because that will always fail